# Why does obj and mtl files not load/work in ar.js?

Tags: file, augmented-reality, ar.js

I don't know why but I can't seem to make this code work:

```
<!-- AR.js by @jerome_etienne - github: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/ar.js - info: https://medium.com/arjs/augmented-reality-in-10-lines-of-html-4e193ea9fdbf -->
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.6.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v4.2.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/master/dist/aframe-extras.loaders.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <a-scene embedded arjs="sourceType: webcam;">
        <a-assets>
            <a-asset-item id="#poster-obj" src ="hx0requiem.github.io/BoysenOBJJJJ.obj"></a-asset-item>
            <a-asset-item id="#poster-mtl" src ="hx0requiem.github.io/BoysenOBJJJJ.mtl"></a-asset-item>
        </a-assets>
        <a-obj-model src="#poster-obj" mtl="poster-mtl"> </a-obj-model>
        <a-marker-camera preset="hiro"></a-marker-camera>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

I tried everything. From using just a .png image and a gltf one. Read the articles and tutorials on how to use obj files in ar.js but everything i tried doesn't seem to be working. Is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get AR.js in general to work, with no objects but just static elements? Are your assets actually requested from the browser? Successfully or with an error message?